# How to modify a data.table column using it as input

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table looking like this:

```
dt <- data.table(
  group_id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  team_id = c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6),
  person_id = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8),
  person_name = c("Smith, J.", "Areta Franklin", "John Smith", "Robert Mitchum", "Robert Mitchum", "Cary Grant", "John Rambo", "Martin Sheen", "Rambo John")
)
```

One person can only be included once in a team, but can appear several times in a group, with name variations (for ex "Smith, J." and "John Smith"). I want to create a new column "uniq_person_id" where all the mentions of a person in the same group would have the same value (for example, "Smith, J." and "John Smith" in group_id = 1).

I created a function `simil_names(name1,name2)` that gives me a score of similarity between name1 and name2, name2 can be a string or a vector of strings, exact matches have a value of 0.

To populate the new column, I tried this:

```
return_id <- function(pid,tid,gid) {
  group <- dt[group_id == gid,]
  person <- as.character(group[person_id == pid & team_id == tid,list(person_name)])
  candidates <- group[uniq_person_id != 0,list(person_name,uniq_person_id)]
  new_id <- 0
  if (nrow(candidates) > 0) {
    candidates$score <- simil_names(person, candidates$person_name)
    if (min(candidates$score) < 2) {
      # If the score is lower than 2, get the id of the best matching person
      new_id <- as.numeric(head(candidates[score == min(candidates$score), list(uniq_person_id)],1))
    } 
  }
  
  # Otherwise compute a new id, incremental
  if(new_id == 0) {
    new_id <- max(group[group_id == gid & team_id == tid,]$uniq_person_id) + 1
  }
  
  return(new_id)
  
}

dt$uniq_person_id <- 0
dt$uniq_person_id <- return_id(dt$person_id,dt$team_id, dt$group_id)
```

I understand that I have the uniq_person_id column is modified only at the end of the execution of the function, that's why it doesn't work. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT

Basically I could not figure out a way of keeping track of modification of dt in the data.table way.

I defined a different value for each row by group_id with `dt[, uniq_person_id := .N:1, by = .(group_id)]` and I tried this:

```
return_id <- function(pid.v,tid.v,gid.v) {
  res.new_ids <- c()
  for(i in c(1:length(gid.v))) {
    gid <- as.numeric(gid.v[i])
    tid <- as.numeric(tid.v[i])
    pid <- as.numeric(pid.v[i])
    
    group <- dt[group_id == gid,]
    person <- as.character(group[person_id == pid & team_id == tid,list(person_name)])
    new_id <- as.numeric(dt[group_id == gid & team_id == tid & person_id == pid,list(uniq_person_id)])
    candidates <- group[uniq_person_id != new_id,list(person_name,uniq_person_id)]
    if (nrow(candidates) > 0) {
      candidates$score <- simil_names(person, candidates$person_name)
      if (min(candidates$score) < 2) {
        # If the score is lower than 2, we change the id with the one of the best matching candidate
        new_id <- as.numeric(head(candidates[score == min(candidates$score), list(uniq_person_id)],1))
      } 
    }
    res.new_ids <- append(res.new_ids,new_id)
  }  
  return(res.new_ids)
}
```

It does not work because it does not keep track in the uniq_person_id column of the already made modifications.

Finally I ended running a loop on each row of dt, with another data.table where I store the ids already modified. If someone has a better idea to do it in the "data.table way", it would be much appreciated.

Comment: How sure are we that `"Smith, J."` and `"John Smith"` are the same person? Perhaps its `Smith, Jane` and not `Smith, John`. This is a difficult problem and unless you have a dictionary, there is no way to group the two together

Comment: Note that there are very many string similarity metrics eg hamming, lavenshtein, cosine, jaccard etc. Even if you choose one, you are not guaranteed to get correct results. eg `John Doe` is very close to `John Smith` than `Smith, J` is to `John Smith`

Comment: I suggest that what you're asking is *"how to know that names are similar-enough to be the same"*, which (as Onyambu said) can be approached with one of those string-distance methods. Even though you are implementing this in `data.table`, the method has nothing to do with the package, so I'm removing the [tag:data.table] and adding [tag:stringdist] to get more-appropriate focused attention.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, due to the particularities of this dataset, "Smith, J."  and "John Smith" are the same person. The function I use to compute the similarity index works well, I use a combination of Levenshtein distance and ordering words. My question is more related to data.table than to stringdist.

Comment: Sometimes the solution can be way simpler, but totally depends on the situation. This looks like some "employee" list where some data had a "free" field to enter names, yielding all your variations. Do you by any chance can get access to the full and correct list of "employees"? If so you can way more reliable correct them without calculating distances.